# Is there a way to query for a certain amount of documents from a database with graphql?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql

Essentially what I want to do is to be able to query, lets say, fruits(0:30). This would give me the 29 documents in the collection regarding fruits. I understand how to query documents and such in graphql, but I do not understand how I would resolve this issue. I see many examples using TypeScript or the files are .graphql and I have no idea what is going on. Is there any possible solution in only node/javascript?

Comment: Did you try this to use this library ? https://graphql.org/graphql-js/

Answer (score 1):

The GraphQL concept of [slicing](https://graphql.org/learn/pagination/#slicing) might be what you're looking for here.

From the learning page linked above:

```
{
  hero {
    name
    friends(first:2) {
      name
    }
  }
}
```